# Inject Javascript on runtime to capture JS errors

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The snippet I used below returns a null value instead I expect the js errors. Is there any alternate way or changes required for this snippet?

```
String script = "window.collectedErrors = [];"
+ "window.onerror = function(errorMessage) { "
+ "window.collectedErrors[window.collectedErrors.length] = errorMessage;"
+ "}";

String error = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
System.out.println(error);
```

The driver used here is Selenium Webdriver to drive the test.

Comment: I believe you need a return in there to get a value back from the script.

Comment: @Richard can you please describe the code; I used - String error = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.collectedErrors"); BUT no luck :(

Comment: I found this: http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/09/capturing-javascript-errors-in.html - You were close, you just need to cast the return correctly.

Comment: Thank you, Richard; Let me try...

Comment: That javascript code snippet only enables the capturing JS errors. So you have to run/invoke that first. To fetch any errors afterwards, you execute this JS "return window.collectedErrors;" That should return an array of Strings I would think. Not sure of exact data type to cast in Java as I've not really tried it out myself.